# delete row with redundant string

Tags: awk, grep

I would like to check a specific pattern / string in a file and if its present in all the columns i want to delete the corresponding line.

Example:

```
name1   name2   name3   name1   name1   name2   name3
name1   name2   name3   name1   name2   name1   
name2   name1   name1   name2   name3   name1   
name2   name2   name2   name2   name2
```

In this file I want to delete row 4 because it contain same name throughout the columns.

I have huge file and number of columns can't be defined manually in awk or grep.

Comment: Please define "escape/del".

Comment: Mean i want to delete that line from the file

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NF>1 { for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) if($i != $1) { print; next } } NF<=1' file
```

With GNU `sed`, or a recent BSD `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^[ \t]*([^ \t]+)([ \t]+\1)+[ \t]*$/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -lane '(@a) = /$F[0]/g; print if $#F != $#a' file 
name1   name2   name3   name1   name1   name2   name3
name1   name2   name3   name1   name2   name1   
name2   name1   name1   name2   name3   name1
```

- Split input line on spaces
- If number of fields is same as number of matches when first column is used as pattern, do not print that line

With `grep` if the file always has same amount of spaces after each column:

```
$ grep -vxE '(\S+\s+)\1*' file 
name1   name2   name3   name1   name1   name2   name3
name1   name2   name3   name1   name2   name1   
name2   name1   name1   name2   name3   name1
```

**Note:** If single column lines should be part of output, use

```
perl -lane '(@a) = /$F[0]/g; print if $#F != $#a || $#F == 0' file
```

and

```
grep -vxE '(\S+\s+)\1+' file
```

Comment: Both patterns will delete lines with a single column.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it in perl might be to map the fields into a hash and then count the resulting keys by evaluating them in a scalar context e.g.

```
$ perl -ane '%names = map { $_ => 1 } @F; print unless keys %names == 1' example
name1 name2 name3 name1 name1 name2 name3
name1 name2 name3 name1 name2 name1
name2 name1 name1 name2 name3 name1
```

or, more compactly, using an anonymous hash

```
$ perl -ane 'print unless keys %{ {map { $_ => 1 } @F } } == 1' example
name1 name2 name3 name1 name1 name2 name3
name1 name2 name3 name1 name2 name1
name2 name1 name1 name2 name3 name1
```

Comment: This will delete lines with a single column.

Comment: Would it be possible to not match the whole character of the cell means name2 but just to match certain string like "name" and based on that exclude the row?